# How to use Github for developing an Arduino library

Tags: git, github, arduino, libraries

I am wondering how to use Github for developing an Arduino library so the library would be recognizable by the Arduino Library straight after the .ZIP install.

I know Git and I know (a bit of) Arduino and ***it seems how Arduino structures his library files make it quite hard to track the changes using GitHub without copying files around all the time***.

In the Arduino side, my library files should reside in the following structure, dictated by Arduino, so the Arduino IDE could recognize it.

```
My Documents > Arduino > libraries > Foo_lib
```

If I want to track this folder using GitHub, I need to give it a repository  name. After doing so and trying to download/clone back the tracked project to my PC I do, one of the thousand ways, like the following,

1. I point the GitHub software to `My Documents > Arduino > libraries >`
2. Press Clone.

However, I end up with the following folder structure

```
My Documents > Arduino > libraries > +GitHub_Repository_Name+ >Foo_lib
```

And now, since my Foo_lib isn't directly under the `libraries` folder, Arduino IDE wouldn't recognize it.

For the 3rd party libs I have always did the download and copying the lib to the `libraries` folder manually, but, this is an ongoing work on the library I am developing myself, so I don't want to make changes, then copy the changes to the tracked folder. (Not that this is hard but it kills me TBH :)

On the other side, if I choose to permanently move the `Foo_lib` folder up a level after cloning, now my `README` files are left in the previous folder and Git freaks out that bunch of files are deleted and the whole thing is a mess.

Is there a suggestion on how to do this from those out there, who develop Arduino libs?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You need to put the library in the root of the repository. Not only will this will solve your issue with using the repository with the Arduino IDE, it will provide a couple additional benefits:

- Allow people to download the repository from GitHub using the **Clone or download > Download ZIP** button on the repository home page and then install the library via **Sketch > Include Library > Add .ZIP Library...**, which requires the library to be in the root of the .zip file.
- Allow you to submit your library for inclusion in the Arduino Library Manager index, which also requires this folder structure.

Note that this doesn't necessarily mean the source files for your library must be in the root of the repository. If you don't care about backwards compatibility with Arduino IDE 1.0.x you can use the "1.5 library format" which allows you to put the library source files in a subfolder named `src`:

https://github.com/arduino/Arduino/wiki/Arduino-IDE-1.5:-Library-specification#source-code

So to proceed you just have to restructure the repository folder structure in your clone, commit the changes, then push them.

Here's an example of how Arduino structures their "1.5 library format" library repositories:

https://github.com/arduino-libraries/Ethernet

As you can see, the library is in the root of the repository.

Comment: Would the downvoter care to give me some constructive criticism on this answer? I have multiple Arduino libraries hosted on GitHub that the local clone is in the `{sketchbook folder}/libraries` folder and it works great provided you have the right repository folder structure.

Comment: I guess some trans-passer was in a bad mood. I'll try your suggestion and get back to you but from the initial reading I am guessing you're suggesting to name my Repo as `Foo_lib` and then put the lib `cpp` and `.h` files on the root which sounds reasonable.

Comment: I don't care about reputation points, I'd just like to improve my answer if it can. Note the part of my answer regarding the `src` subfolder if you don't want to put your source files in the root. I do put them in the root of my repositories because there are still people using Arduino IDE 1.0.x and I like to support backwards compatibility but I think that's becoming less important as more of them switch over to the newer IDE versions.

Comment: It's a good idea to give the repository the same name as the main .h file but not required. The IDE will search all library folders for the included file but if there are multiple files with the same name the one with the name matching the library folder containing it gets priority. This causes problems for users sometimes, especially with the Arduino-IRremote library, which has the same header filename as the rarely used RobotIRremote library included with the IDE. Since neither of the files have a matching folder name the one in the RobotIRremote folder gets included.